# Exercise 2.5.13 Friedberg: Is it well justified the first part of this proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Exercise 2.5.13 Friedberg**:

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$, and
let $\beta = (x_{1}, \ldots , x_{n})$ be an ordered basis for V. Let $Q$
be an $n \times n$ invertible matrix with entries from $\mathbb{F}$. Define
\begin{align*}
    x_{j}'= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} Q_{ij} x_{i}  \text{ for } 1 \leq j \leq n,
  \end{align*}
and set $\beta'=(x_{1}', \ldots , x_{n}')$. Prove that $\beta'$ is a basis
$V$ and hence that $Q$ is the change of coordinate matrix changing
$\beta'$-coordinates into $\beta$-coordinates.

**Proof:**

By definition of $x_{j}'$, and using the standard representation of $V$
with respect to $\beta$:
\begin{align*}
  \phi_{\beta}(x_{j}')=[x_{j}']^{\beta}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    Q_{1j} \\
    \vdots \\
    Q_{nj} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \text{ for each } 1 \leq j \leq n
\end{align*}
Notice that:
\begin{align*}
    0 = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} a_{j} \phi_{\beta}(x_{j}') = Q \cdot 
    \begin{pmatrix}
      a_1 \\
      \vdots \\
      a_n \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
And since $Q$ is invertible by hypothesis:
\begin{align*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      a_1 \\
      \vdots \\
      a_n \\
    \end{pmatrix} = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0 \\
      \vdots \\
      0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Therefore $ \{ \phi_{\beta}(x_{j}') \}_{j=1,\ldots,n} $
is linearly independent, hence is a basis for $\mathbb{F}^{n}$ by Corollary 2
of the Replacement Theorem (since $\dim(\mathbb{F}^{n})=n$).

Also $\phi_{\beta}$ is an isomorphism then
there exist an inverse $\phi_{\beta}^{-1}$ that is also an isomorphism,
then:
\begin{align*}
  \{ (\phi_{\beta}^{-1} \circ \phi_{\beta} ) (x_{j}')  \}_{j=1,\ldots,n} = 
  \{ x_{j}' \}_{j=1,\ldots,n}
\end{align*}
By a result from Exercise 2.1.14 (c) an
isomorphism(i.e.$\phi_{\beta}^{-1}$ bijective ) takes a basis to a basis,
therefore $\{ x_{j}' \}_{j=1,\ldots,n}$ is a basis of $V$.

For the second part of the proof let $I_{V}: V \to V$ such that:
\begin{align*}
I_{V}(x_{j}')=x_{j}'=\sum_{i = 1}^{n} Q_{ij} x_{i}  \text{ for } 1 \leq j \leq n,
   \end{align*}
Then by the matrix representation of $I_{V}$:
\begin{align*}
[I_{V}]_{\beta'}^{\beta} = Q
   \end{align*}
Therefore Q is the change of coordinate matrix changing
$\beta'$-coordinates into $\beta$-coordinates.

**(End of proof).**

I worked through this proof, and **the step** I am not sure about is this one:

- Also $\phi_{\beta}$ is an isomorphism then
  there exist an inverse $\phi_{\beta}^{-1}$ that is also an isomorphism,
  then:
  \begin{align*}
    \{ (\phi_{\beta}^{-1} \circ \phi_{\beta} ) (x_{j}')  \}_{j=1,\ldots,n} = 
    \{ x_{j}' \}_{j=1,\ldots,n}
  \end{align*}
  By a result from Exercise 2.1.14 (c) an
  isomorphism(i.e.$\phi_{\beta}^{-1}$ bijective ) takes a basis to a basis,
  therefore $\{ x_{j}' \}_{j=1,\ldots,n}$ is a basis of $V$.

**The question:** Why finding the basis
$ \{ \phi_{\beta}(x_{1}'), \ldots ,\phi_{\beta}(x_{n}') \} $  of $\mathbb{F}^{n}$ together with the existence of $\phi_{\beta}^{-1}$
is enough to say that $\{ x_{1}', \ldots , x_{n}' \}$ is a basis of $V$?

Thanks in advance, appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Generally, this is not a "here's my proof, tell me if it is correct" site. If there is a *specific* step you are not sure about, then you should clearly identify it, and clearly state *why* you are not sure about it. Otherwise, the post is "too broad" and unsuitable for the site. Also, the post doesn't start in the title. The title should have a clear and short description of the mathematical content of your post, and the post should not rely on the title line to make sense. Letters don't start on the envelope, and posts don't start in the title.

Comment: Thanks @Arturo Magidin I took into account your suggestions.